# To find label column width while Reading Excel File in C#

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I am reading an excel file from a WPF application. For some purpose I need the column width as per in the label ("A", "B", "C" ... in the excel sheet). The width variable in the Range always provides the particular cells width. If the cell belongs to a merged cell (previous column or previous row), reading the perticular cell width, results in a null. So, I need the width of the column labels or the height of row labels ("1", "2", ...) not the cell height !

KB

Answer (score 0):

Find your `Range` (`Application.Selection` or `Application.ActiveCell` or `Range[..,..]` , ...)

and use [`Range.ColumnWidth`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.columnwidth). for column width:

```
var width = worksheet.Range["A1", "A5"].ColumnWidth;
```

and use `Range.Value` or `Range.Parse` for values of range.

```
var value = worksheet.Range["A1", "A5"].Value;
```

Working with `Range` have more benefits!

Comment: Thanks! But as said above I need for each column. Range["A1","A3"] or any thing such will give width of the cell. This may vary depending on which cell you are reading and whether it is merged with other cell. So I need individual column width irrespective of merger. 'A' 'B' 'C' ... column widths. I don't know any method is available to know this. I can't try with cell. For example, A3 and A4 are merged, reading A4 width gives null value. I need to display some information according to Excel columnwise data irrespective of merger. So, I need that label width.

Comment: @user1530713: My code is a sample of using `Range.ColumnWidth`. You can use `worksheet.Range["A1", "A5"].ColumnWidth;` or other strategies for giveing `Range` (like naming ranges) can be helpful. but at the end you have to use `Range.ColumnWidth`.

Comment: Thank you! I could able to get the label width. Is there any way to read the content of the cell which has been merged ? cell.Value2 will result in null, if the previous cell is merged. Is there any way such that being in one of the merged cells (not the first one), I can read the value of the merged content ?

Comment: Thanks Ria ! But I have some peculiar requirement ! My excel sheet has got many merged cells, rowwise/columnwise. The excel sheet is of 2000+ rows and 50+ columns! While displaying columnwise cell value, I come across merged cells. For first merged cell, no issue. But for the second and so on, it will be null. If I know, from where the merge started, at least I can take the reading from that cell till the range. for ex, A3 to A6 are merged. I am having handle for A5:A5 range only, can I anyway know that merge starting and ending cell with handle A5 ?